# Mathematics in ylabel

Tags: expression, axis-labels

Good day

I want to write Ri+ and Ri- (i as subscript and +/- as superscript) on y label in a basic plot function in Rstudio. Also "and" between them. I am trying

expression(italic("R"["i"]^"+"~"R"["i"]^"-"))

But this is not working as I am desired. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
expression(paste(italic(R[i]^+phantom(0)),"and", italic(~R[i]^-phantom(0))))
```